# django html2text anchor breaking

Tags: django

While sending html and pain-text with MIMEMultipart('alternative')

When converting html to text the anchor of html is breaking in new line

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/some-url/other-part-of-url

to

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/some-
>
> url/other-part-of-url

Why this is happening?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you try to do, i.e. why you try to convert the incoming URL into text?

Comment: This is happening while I was trying to convert html content to pain-text using django html2text. In html the url showing in one line but after converting the url is breaking in random point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

django *html2text(content,baseUrl,length)* has 3 parameter in constructor where the third one is length(default 78). You can increase the length by using that.